# Times loop does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a simple helper for my rails application:

```
def calendar_build
    5.times do 
      whole_cal
    end
  end

  def whole_cal
      content_tag(:div, :class => "row") do
        small_cal + big_cal
      end
  end

  def small_cal
    content_tag(:div, :class => "col-xs-2 token-text") do
      concat(content_tag(:p, "15.20"))
    end
  end
  def big_cal
    content_tag(:div, :class => "col-xs-10 weite_cal") do
      concat(content_tag(:input,"", class: "form-control input-sm pa"))
    end
  end
```

How you can see i try to generate 5 `whole_cal`:

```
    def calendar_build
        5.times do 
          whole_cal
        end
      end
```

But in my view this only displays `5` why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do `whole_cal*5`? String multiplication works in general.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the loop is 5.

```
1.9.3p194 :056 > 5.times {}
 => 5
```

You should probably do

```
  def calendar_build
   whole_cals = []
    5.times do 
      whole_cals << whole_cal
    end
   whole_cals
  end
```

And iterate the array in your view

Comment: This returns the whole code in a array to the view it isnt renderd as html `["<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-xs-2 token-text\"><p>1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the generated html code to a variable like result, then put result as last line in your method to return the concatenated code

something like:

```
result = ""

5.times do
  result += html code
end

result
```

and depending on your html code, you should replace the last line with result.html_safe